# Getting a sum of image widths and applying that sum to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div containing a bunch of images. The height of each image is 100% of the window and the width is dynamic, based on that window height. I want to grab the displayed width of the images, get their sum, and apply that to the container.

The problem is that I'm grabbing the native width, but I'd like to be grabbing the displayed width. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var width = 0;
$('.index .main-content img').each(function() {
    width += $(this).width();
});

$('.index .main-content').css( 'width', width );
```

I'm thinking maybe I have to apply the css after the images have been loaded? I can't really figure out the syntax.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: I may not totally follow, but perhaps you want to make the image widths a percentage of the div and make the div's width depend on the window size?

Comment: define native width vs displayed width ?

Comment: Let's say the image is 8000px by 8000px, but shows up in the window as 2000px by 2000px. The former would be the native width and the latter would be the displayed width.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var sum = 0;

      var addImageWidthToContainer = function(el){
        sum += $(el).width();
        console.log(sum)
      }

      $('.pics').each(function(i, el){
        $(el).on('load', addImageWidthToContainer(el));
      });
   });
```